# MWPhotoBrowser: Show captions for every photo

Tags: ios

I'm using MWPhotoBrowser in my iOS app. I would like the controls and captions to remain visible until the user taps to dismiss the controls and caption. When I swipe to move to the next photo, the caption and toolbar disappear. I would like it to toggle between visible and hidden when the user taps the photo. If the user taps to show the caption and then swipes to see the next photo, the caption disappears again. I would like it to stay visible

I don't see anything in the public interface on the MWPhotoBrowser which allows me to control this behavior. There are a couple of private methods that are related, but I wanted to find out if there is a proper way to control this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether its too late for this answer but still you need to edit the `MWPhotoBrowser` class and find for `- (void)hideControlsAfterDelay;` method call just comment it to make it visible all the time or you can add this method to delegate and can control this behavior from your end.